# Getting labels for multiple uri's in a single sparql query

Tags: sparql

If we have a set of URI's, how do we get the labels for all of them in a SINGLE SPARQL QUERY?

ie. Given, uri1, uri2, uri3 ...
we want the query to give us

uri1 label1

uri2 label2

uri3 label3

While we could issue separate queries for getting the labels for each uri, we would ideally like to avoid making a large number of requests.

I have tried to think in terms of construct, unions and subqueries,  with little success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say how the labels are expressed in your RDF data, so I assume that they're connected to the URIs with the `rdfs:label` property. Then the query is simply this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?uri ?label { ?uri rdfs:label ?label }
```

If you want only the labels for only specific URIs, you can get that by filtering on the `?uri` variable:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?uri ?label {
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label
    FILTER (?uri = ex:resource1 || ?uri = ex:resource2 || ?uri = ex:resource3)
}
```

Or, if your store supports SPARQL 1.1:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?uri ?label {
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label
    FILTER (?uri IN (ex:resource1, ex:resource2, ex:resource3))
}
```

Comment: The above query will give us the labels for all the uri's in the dataset. For a very large dataset, this would result in a very large response. What we want is a query that gives us labels for a small set of specific uris (say 20).

Comment: Slightly nicer in SPARQL 1.1: 

FILTER (?uri IN (ex:resource1 , ex:resource2 , ex:resource3) )

Comment: Thanks cygri and andyS! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Cathy, you can best show your appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting answers that you found helpful :-)

Comment: Sure cygri! (the least I can do!) Upvoting is associated with reputation thresholds. So will need to wait a bit before I can do that! Have accepted the answer though (didn't realize that this does not require minimum reputation). thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there is a restriction on voting. Thanks for the green check mark!